# Orientation attribute of StackPanel defined as top level component in separate xaml file ignored

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am defining a StackPanel in a file called HPanel.xaml like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" />
```

Then, using the HPanel like this:

```
<v:HPanel>
  <Label Content="The label" />
  <TextBox Text="{Binding transporter.Foo, 
    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</v:HPanel>
```

Will give me a stackpanel with vertical orientation instead of horizontal.

Why?

Comment: I see no apparent reason for this behavior. Can you post more code? like exactly how you include your files (resource dictionaries and so on...) and the complete code for your HPanel.xaml class if possible

Comment: HPanel.xaml do only consist of that line. The control that had the HPanel as child did not have a resource dictionary. Stackpanel is not mentioned in generic.xaml. The HPanel is inside another StackPanel. If I change the inclusion you can see above (<v:HPanel> etc...) to StackPanel with Orientation="Horizontal", the orientation will be correct.

Comment: there's something missing here... "HPanel.xaml do only consist of that line" << this seems impossible to me: you would need a {x:Class="HPanel"} somewhere for the <v:HPanel> to compile without error. Could you really not post the *entire* content of the HPanel.xaml file? with the xmls:x .... stuff? I have a feeling the problem lies with those missing lines of code

Comment: You were right, code behind must be there, so below, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tada!

I have made a working test case now, the stackpanel becomes nice if I have a code behind. InitializeComponent was needed for attributes to be processed.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="wpftestapp.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:v="clr-namespace:wpftestapp.views"
     Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <v:HPanel>
      <Label Content="a"/>
      <Label Content="b"/>
      <Label Content="c"/>
    </v:HPanel>
</Window>
```

HPanel.xaml:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
    x:Class="wpftestapp.views.HPanel"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"/>
```

HPanel.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace wpftestapp.views
{
  public partial class HPanel : StackPanel
  {
    public HPanel()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ah yes, that would explain it indeed. So I was quite right in wanting to know more about the HPanel class in the end ^^ glad it helped you figure things out.